# how to use c() to generate a sequence of real numbers in r?

Tags: r, data-analysis

I know that using `c(*start_no*:*end_no*)` in R returns a sequence of numbers from *start_no* to *end_no* like

```
> c(1:10)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

But I want `c()` to print in the following pattern

```
> c(0.1:0.9)
 [1]  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9
```

Ideas on how to accomplish this by only using c() in R?

Comment: You can use `seq` i.e. `seq(0.1, 0.9, by =0.1)` or `(1:10)/10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you cannot directly use it. However, you can manipulate it like

```
c(1:10)/10

# [1] 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
```

Comment: ok..i saw it now. Sure, i will delete my answer. Just a question. when do we post a solution as an answer and when as comment?

Comment: I thought you had seen the comment.  Sorry then.  It looked to me that it was a blatant copy without even acknowledging.  You can keep it.